# Is it Safe to Copy a Private Key Using SCP?

Tags: encryption

Is it safe to copy a private key from one computer to another over SCP? Does this depend on whether you use the same key to authenticate the transfer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SCP uses SSH for transport, and that's considered to be a robust protocol, about as safe as you can get. It does not matter whether the data which is encrypted is itself a copy of a private key involved in the establishment of the SSH tunnel; it would be a terrible weakness of the protocol if it did matter (and, in the case of SSH, the "keys" as seen by users are used only for signatures, at the start of the connection, but are unrelated to the symmetric keys used for actual data encryption).

However, using SCP to transfer a piece of secret data (e.g. a key) means that the secret data exists as a *file* on the source computer, and will be written as another file on the destination computer. Files leave traces on a physical medium (that's the point), so the secrecy of that transferred key is subordinate to your management of the two involved hard disks (on source and destination) throughout their life cycle. Don't simply discard old disks ! Have them shredded into small pieces if you cannot ensure their logical devastation when they reach their end of life (for instance, if a disk fails, then you cannot wipe out the contents by overwriting the whole disk area with zeros).

One may also state that the more a private key is copied, the less "private" it becomes.

Comment: Good point about failed disks being undestroyable, but if a disk has failed physically, wouldn't that also discourage a recovery attack?